# Gram-Schmidt process for polynomial space

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

I'm looking for a orthonormal basis to 2 polynomials $f,g ∈ \Bbb R_2[x]$
we will define inner product space:
$<f,g>=f\left(0\right)\cdot g\left(0\right)+f\left(1\right)\cdot \:g\left(1\right)+f\left(2\right)\cdot \:\:g\left(2\right)$
I know how to do Gram-Schmidt process to vectors
But how do you make it for polynomial?
**
For example in vectors it is easy to see vectors like $\vec v=(0,1),\vec u=(1,0)$
And see that all vectors in $\Bbb R_2$ can appear as linear combination of $\vec v,\vec u$
**
But how does it work with polynomials?
Thank you.

Comment: You can translate it all to $\Bbb R^3$ by the correspondence $a+bx+cx^2\mapsto (a,b,c)$, but instead of the ordinary inner product, you need the corresponding translation of the given inner product.

Answer (score 1):

> Definition: A vectorial space $V$ over some field $F$ is a vectorial space with inner product if there exists and function $<.>: V \times V \longrightarrow F$ su h that for any
> $u,v,w\in V$ and $\alpha \in F$:

$<v,v> \, >0$

$<v,v>=0$ iff $v=0$

$<u,v>=\overline{<u,v>}$

$<u,v+w>=<u,v>+<u,w>$

$<u+w,v>=<u,v>+<w,v>$

$<\alpha u,v>=\alpha <u,v>$

> Definition: Let $V$ a vector space with inner product over some field $F$,given $v\in V$ we define the norm of $v$ by  $||v||=\sqrt{<v,v>}$

> ${\displaystyle \mathrm {proj} _{\mathbf {u} }\,(\mathbf {v} )={\langle \mathbf {u} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle  \over \langle \mathbf {u} ,\mathbf {u} \rangle }{\mathbf {u} },}$

Finally given a finite vector space $V$ over $F$, with inner product, then $V$ have a ortonormal basis.

> Construction

Let $S= \lbrace v_1,v_2, \cdots v_n \rbrace $ basis of $V$.Pick $v_1\in S$.
$u_1=v_1$

$u_2=v_2-Proj_{u_1}(v_2)$

$u_3=v_3-Proj_{u_1}(v_3)-Proy_{u_2}(v_3)$

and notice

$u_n=v_n-\sum_{j=1}^{n}{Proy_{u_j}(v_n)}$

And consider $e_i=\frac{u_i}{||U_i||}$

Then the set $U=\lbrace e_1,e_2, \cdots, e_n \rbrace$ is a ortonormal basis of $V$.

In your case you had that the polinomials are a vector space with inner product given by
$<p,q>=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{a_ib_i}$ where $a_i,b_i$  are the coeficients of your polinomial(you can comprove it).

Now you only had to follow the process.

I hope that my comment helps you

Comment: Thanks for the response.
when we talk about polynomials,how to find a basis from nothing(to run the process on him)?
we need a group to represent each of the components of the polynomial like:
$S={1,x...x^n}?$

Comment: You need begin from one polinomial say $v_1$ the next step is consider other polinomial $v_2$ such that $v_2\not \in Span( \lbrace v_1\rbrace) $  and consider the set that contains $v_1,v_2$ and let $v_3$ such that $v_3 \not \in Span( \lbrace v_1,v_2 \rbrace )$ and continue this process to complet the dimention of $V$